# Is there a clean way to ignore case when comparing List<String>?

Tags: java, string, list

Right now I've got something like:

```
boolean areListsDifferent = (list1.size() == list2.size()) ? false : true;
for(String string : list1){
    if(!list2.contains(string.toLowerCase())){
        // This sucks because it assumes list2 is all lower case, 
        // which is probably true but presumptuous
        areListsDifferent = true;
    }
}
return areListsDifferent;
```

And that seems kinda verbose for this, plus I'd really rather not make the assumption about the second list being all lower case. It makes it much more brittle for future changes.

Is there a better way?

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase()` is what you are looking for it seems.

Comment: A `List` is an *ordered* collection of elements. Two lists are generally only the same if ordering matches, and your code ignores order. Is that your intent?

Comment: You are assuming there are no duplicates. for example `A, b, b, b` would match `a, a, b, b` or `a, B, B, B`

Comment: Since you're not returning after checking the lists' sizes, you're going to iterate through both lists even if you've already determined they are different. Stick a return statement after the size check.

Comment: Order doesn't matter. Duplicates don't really matter either. For this scenario, returning true when the lists are functionally the same just means an idempotent operation gets run wastefully, so it isn't a big deal. The only important thing is to never ever return true if the lists ARE different.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are comparing sizes, I'll assume that order is relevant, as lists are ordered collections. The code shown in the question ignores order.

To compare all elements case-insensitively, in order, you should parallel iterate both lists. Since `get(int)` is not fast for all `List` implementations, a parallel iteration using `Iterator` is best:

```
private static boolean equalsIgnoreCase(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    if (list1.size() != list2.size())
        return false;
    for (Iterator<String> iter1 = list1.iterator(), iter2 = list2.iterator(); iter1.hasNext(); )
        if (! iter1.next().equalsIgnoreCase(iter2.next()))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to **compare** 2 lists.

Ensure neither list is null.

```
if(list1 == null || list2 == null) return false;
```

Check sizes.

```
if(list1.size() != list2.size()) return false;
```

Check elements in lists (including the ordering of strings(?), but not casing)

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < list1.size() ; i++) {
    // i think equalsIgnoreCase takes care of null strings
    // if it doesn't, do it yourself :)
    String first = list1.get(i);
    String second = list2.get(i);
    if(first == null && second != null)
        return false;
    if(first == null && second == null)
        continue;
    if( !(first.equalsIgnoreCase(second)) )
        return false;
}
```

If you got here. Everything is probably good.

```
return true;
```

As Andreas noted, for lists that are implemented like `LinkedList` the get(..) gives bad performance. An `iterator` based approached like his answer solves that issue.

Comment: Using `get()` gives bad performance if the lists are `LinkedList` or other non-array implementation. --- `equalsIgnoreCase` does not take care of null on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Following your clarification:

> Order doesn't matter. Duplicates don't really matter either.

Then I would do this by first putting the data into some kind of `SortedSet`, which has these properties. Something like:

```
var set1 = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
var set2 = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
set1.addAll(list1);
set2.addAll(list2);
return set1.equals(set2);
```

This should run faster (`O(N log N)`) than looping over one list & repeatedly calling `contains` on the other one (`O(N^2)`) - significantly so once your lists have more than ~10 elements.